# Personal accounting solution available for India

Tags: finance, accounting

I need a personal accounting software, preferably in Linux or cloud based.

- I need it to be simple to use.
  So, I need a GUI interface.
- I should be able to input all transactions manually.
- I should be able to generate a report of every account.
- No need for future expense tracking or things like that.
- Should be easy to create new accounts especially expense accounts.
- My ideal price would be free. But I think I can manage 1usd per month.

It should be available for Indian users (some are not available, I don't know why).

PS:

- I tried **GNU Cash**. Failed miserably to understand it.
- Can't use **mint.com** as it's not available for India.

Comment: If your question was answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: Still looking for a better one. YNAB is ok, but pricey.

Comment: Ledger is text based. I need a GUI

Comment: Please edit your question to describe *all* your requirements (including a GUI and the maximum you're willing to pay).

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Jacob, you have to try harder - either in paying for professionally developed software, or in understanding and using the free ones. Better yet, try to find an accountant to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ledger](http://ledger-cli.org/) meets your requirements.

- "in Linux" — Check.
- "simple to use" — Check. Type your transactions in a simple format with a text editor, then type commands like `ledger reg` to show a register or `ledger bal food` to show the total amount attributed to accounts with "food" in their name.
- "able to input all transactions manually" — Check, with a text editor.
- "able to generate a report of every account" — Check. Pretty much any imaginable report can be produced.
- "easy to create new accounts" — Check. You don't have to do anything to create an account. It's created automatically the first time you include it in a transaction.
- "available for Indian users" — Check.
- gratis — Check.

Edit: since you want a GUI, you could try [hledger](http://hledger.org/), a reimplementation of Ledger that includes a graphical web interface.

Comment: Ahem, "I tried GNU Cash. Failed miserably to understand it." and "So, I need a GUI interface." Do you think recommending ledger-cli makes any sense after these statements?

Comment: @AlenSiljak I can't speak for GnuCash, but OP requested a GUI after I wrote this answer. In the edit I made in response, I added a reference to a GUI for Ledger.

Comment: fair enough. I see no conceptual difference between GnuCash and ledger. Both are double-entry accounting programs. My suspicion is, therefore, that the OP does not understand the double entry accounting in the first place. In any case, it would help if he elaborated on what were the problems with GnuCash. Then we might be able to point out other solutions, if available, that avoid those pitfalls. I agree that ledger is a fantastic piece of software but it might be overkill if someone can't handle GUI like GnuCash.

Answer (score 1):

[You Need A Budget (YNAB)](https://www.youneedabudget.com/) should have what you are looking for.

- Cloud-based.
- It is very simple to use, and offers free online classes to help you get started.  It is much easier than GNU Cash.
- Transactions can be entered manually.  (That is how I use it.)  It can connect to a bank and download transactions automatically, but I don't think that feature is available for Indian banks yet.
- You can create as many accounts as you want.

They offer a 34-day free trial, so you can try it out before you buy.

If you are interested, I've written a little more about using personal finance software (and YNAB in particular) in a few posts on Money.SE:

- [How do you verify your household budget?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/47446/10997)
- [Best personal finance strategy to control my balance](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/56420/10997)
- [How are the “Credit Card Payments” categories supposed to work in the web version of YNAB?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/62539/10997)

Comment: Its pricey. Other than that, its OK.